# downloaded STS, how to import/open petcare?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, petcare

The spring website says:

> The petcare sample application
>   referenced in this presentation can
>   also be accessed in the Spring Samples
>   SVN repository. This sample app is
>   directly importable & runnable with
>   SpringSource Tool Suite

I downloaded the spring tool suite, can't find any import mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Right-click** in the **Package Explorer** view then **Import...**